# two instances of tinymce with jquery ui causes chrome page to hang and be not responding

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, tinymce, cpu

in the cpanel that i'm developing thre is a department for articles in arabic and english
so i used two tinymce editors one for arabic and the other is for english it works as expected, but the problem is that when i'm using chrome browser the page suddenly become not responding  and never come back and i need to restart it but in IE8 no problem at all.
i've found in chrome task manager that the memory usage of the page is over 22 kilobyte.
i'm also using jquery ui.
i've tried the following
1- using jquery plugin the compressor tiny_mce_gzip.php
2- decreasing the plugins of tinymce [ispell,layers,..]

what is the solution or what is the cause

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that jquery or jquery ui is the point here.
I already had some issues likethis concering an older jquery version leading to an endless loop.

Using the latest jquery version was the solution back then.

Comment: thanks for response but i'm using the latest jquery library. i downloaded it long before starting the project since 4 weeks!.and because it works fine on IE(?????) now i tried to finish the project then try another version or the YUI Compressor to compress jquery - http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/02/how-to-use-yuicompressor-to-compress.html , hopping to find the final solution